# hook_node_grants not invoked in drupal-7

Tags: module, drupal-7, admin, message

### i use "hook_node_grants()" in my module but it never run (invoke).

note that "hook_node_access_records" is right.

```
    function mymodule_node_grants($account, $op) {
      dpm($op);
      $grants = array();
      if ($op == 'view' || $op == 'update') {
        $grants['guser'] = array($account->uid);
      }
      return $grants;
    }

function mymodule_node_access_records($node) {
  if (!empty($node->guser)) {
    $grants = array();
    $grants[] = array(
      'realm' => 'guser',
      'gid' => user_load_by_name(array('name' => $node->guser))->uid,
      'grant_view' => 1,
      'grant_update' => 1,
      'grant_delete' => 1,
      'priority' => 1,
    );
    return $grants;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83209/hook-node-grants-implemented-by-a-custom-module-is-not-invoked) post will help you.

To summarize, if you are testing this code logged in as an Administrator (UserID: 1) *hook_node_grants* will not be invoked.

Also, looking at some of the [source code](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access/7) that hook will not be invoked if the role of the user you are authenticated with has the *bypass node access* permission enabled.